# Diffing for metadata differences

Tags: diff, file-metadata

Is there are way to use utility like `diff` to find the difference in metadata of two identical file hierarchies? If I have two identical file structures like

```
root_folder/
    file1
    file2
    folder1/
        file3
```

The `diff` utility will usually exit as though they are identical but adding them to tarballs will produce different hashes. This indicates differences in metadata like timestamps, ownership, etc. but I would like to know what are the exact differences and the default behavior of `diff` doesn't help me there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend [`diffoscope`](https://diffoscope.org/) in this sort of situation.

You can run it before creating the tarballs, as

```
diffoscope dir1 dir2
```

to find the differences between the two directories (including metadata), or after creating them, as

```
diffoscope tarball1.tar tarball2.tar
```

to find the differences between the two tarballs.

Comment: A good tool available on most platforms - thanks!